# C# when in Control's life cycle is Site (ISite) not null?

Tags: c#, winforms, service

I have a form

```
MyForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form {}
```

and I need to call

```
Site.GetService(..)
```

before user starts using this form.

But it's null in constructor and all loading events I've tried to override.
When is the **Site** not null, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `IComponent.Site` is set only in the Visual Studio designer. It is used for design-time services within the IDE such as naming the component. Here is an article that talks about how sites are used: [Design-Time Integration—Hosts, Containers, and Sites](https://web.archive.org/web/20130224105204/http://en.csharp-online.net/Design-Time_Integration%E2%80%94Hosts,_Containers,_and_Sites).